# Undefined value of attribute in multiple select option tag

Tags: jquery

I have this multiple select tag and script:

```js
$('#prod11').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected', this);
    var results = [];

    selected.each(function() {
        results.push($(this).data('email'));
    });


    alert(results);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker w-100" multiple="" id="prod11" name="prod[]" data-style="form-control-lg btn-info" tabindex="-98">
    <option selected disabled> בחר מפיק</option>
    <option value=""> </option>
    <?php foreach ($prod_res as $prod) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $prod['user_first'] ?> <?= $prod['user_last'] ?>" phone="<?= $prod['user_phone']?>" email="<?= $prod['user_email'] ?>" data-id="<?= $prod['user_id'] ?>">
        <?= $prod['user_first'] ?>
        <?= $prod['user_last'] ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="prod_email[]" class="prod_email">
<input type="hidden" name="prod_phone[]" class="prod_phone">
<input type="hidden" name="prod_id[]" class="prod_id">
```

I am trying to get the attribute of phone email and data ID but all I am getting is `undefined`, I tried several scripts but none of them work,
I am using bootstrap `selectpicker` class,

Comment: Side note; `$(this).find('option:selected', this);` <= passing `this` into the `find()` there is unnecessary.  Your context is already defined by you calling it off of the `$(this)`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how you are getting the email and phone fields with the logic you have provided.  They are not `data-*` fields.  Also this logic provided is not trying to get anything but the email field.  You need to show us the version that you are using that is trying to get all of them that is not working.

Comment: what a stupid mistake data-* I have change them to data-email - data-phone and it's working now! thank you!!